# Deploy SSIS with Powershell - Missing DMF

Tags: powershell, ssis

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to deploy and SSIS project.  Here is my code.

```
# Variables
$SSISNamespace = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"
$TargetServerName = "FBISQL003DV"
$TargetFolderName = "DEV"
$ProjectFilePath = "C:\Users\Brian.Ciampa\source\Workspaces\TFICM2\TFCIM\DEV\CIM\SSIS\BC_TEST\bin\Development\BC_TEST.ispac"
$ProjectName = "BC_TEST"

# Load the IntegrationServices assembly.  This is located at C:\windows\assembly.
$loadStatus = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.IntegrationServices, "+
    "Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL")

# Create a connection to the server
$sqlConnectionString = `
    "Data Source=" + $TargetServerName + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionString

# Create the Integration Services object
$integrationServices = New-Object $SSISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection

# Get the Integration Services catalog
$catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]

# Create the target folder
$folder = New-Object $SSISNamespace".CatalogFolder" ($catalog, $TargetFolderName,
    "Folder description")
$folder.Create()

Write-Host "Deploying " $ProjectName " project ..."

# Read the project file and deploy it
[byte[]] $projectFile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ProjectFilePath)
$folder.DeployProject($ProjectName, $projectFile)

Write-Host "Done."
```

However, I keep getting this message:

```
New-Object : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.Common, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At C:\Users\Brian.Ciampa\desktop\SSIS_Deploy.ps1:20 char:24
+ ... nServices = New-Object $SSISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConne ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

The Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.dll and the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.Common.dll files are located in the folder.  What do I need to do?

Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the dll using Add-Type like so:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.Common, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
```

It will check in the current directory for the dll, unless it's already been successfully loaded previously.

If you still get not found, the version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.Common.dll in the folder is not the dll needed by the IntegrationServices assembly.

To check the signature of the dll in the current folder, you can run:

```
([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile((Get-Item ".\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.Common.dll").FullName)).FullName
```

Notes to help locate matching dlls.

```
12.0 = SQL Server 2014
13.0 = SQL Server 2016
14.0 = SQL Server 2017
```

Alternate Option:

In the case below, I'll initially load IntegrationServices "Version 14.0.0..." so that the dll doesn't need to be manually loaded from file or added to GAC.

```
C:\>attrib /s gacutil.exe
A            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
A            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe
A            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\gacutil.exe
A            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe
A            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
A            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe

C:\>cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64>gacutil /l | find "IntegrationServices,"
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64>gacutil /l | find "Dmf.Common,"
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64>gacutil /l | find "Dmf,"
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64>
```

Comment: Didn't work.  I got this message:  Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.Common, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' could not be found.

Comment: That specific dll file can't be used to fill the dependency needed by the specified IntegrationServices assembly.   Use the signature command I appended above to help locate matching versions.    One or the other needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  The dll I'm pointing to has a version of 15.  So, I need a 13 version?

Comment: Yes, but also consider alternative option added to post.   This would only address the could not load file or assembly issue noted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with deploying an SSIS project with PowerShell. Eventually, I ended up deploying the project with a T-SQL script:

```
DECLARE @ProjectBinary as varbinary(max)
DECLARE @operation_id as bigint
Set @ProjectBinary = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Brian.Ciampa\source\Workspaces\TFICM2\TFCIM\DEV\CIM\SSIS\BC_TEST\bin\Development\BC_TEST.ispac', SINGLE_BLOB) as BinaryData)    

Exec catalog.deploy_project @folder_name = 'DEV', @project_name = 'BC_TEST', @Project_Stream = @ProjectBinary, @operation_id = @operation_id out
```

Later I wrapped it into a stored procedure and triggered it with the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet from PowerShell.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after migrating my work to a new laptop. What solved it was simply installing SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition (you can download it for free from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads). Be sure to include all the features which mention SDK and connectivity components. After I did this, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I came here to this question, while I was looking for solution for missing DMT.

I installed this:
Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Service Pack 2 Feature Pack

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56833

1. ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi
2. ENU\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi

And it was important for me to have **x86** version. Then I could check in cmd dlls like @vhoang wrote:

```
>cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools"
>gacutil /l | find "Dmf,"

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL

>gacutil /l | find "Dmf.Common,"

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.Common, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```